# ECS Fargate - Can a container access its own Public IP address

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I am deploying JVM applications in Fargate. I need to be able to determine the public IP address within the application. Is this directly possible at all? I have tried the task metadata endpoints, but only seem to be able to access the private IP address.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use an external service, such as `curl ifconfig.me`. If you don't like doing that you can get `TaskARN` from the tesk metadata. Once you have the arn, you can use AWS SDK/CLI to get ENI id of your task using `describe-tasks` api call, and then query the ENI to get its public Ip using `describe-network-interfaces`.